# Componente personalizado que tenga un campo de texto y un campo de selección usando React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui

me gustaría crear un componente personalizado que pueda usar un campo de texto y un campo para seleccionar alguna opción usando React MUI, he buscado en la biblioteca pero no he encontrado nada, además lo intenté hacer y no queda bien aquí está mi código:

```
<TextField
  value={value.text}
  onChange={onChange}
  {...rest}
  InputProps={{
  endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position='end'>
      <TextField
        select
        name='option'
        value={value.option}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...selectProps}
        sx={{ '.MuiSelect-select': { border: 'none' } }}
       >
         {options.map((option) => (
         <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
           {option}
         </MenuItem>
       ))}
      </TextField>
    </InputAdornment>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

El componente TextFieldWithOptions recoge un evento con los valores de ambos un TextField normal y un TextField select, estos dos valores son enviados como un objeto dentro del value del target del evento para su uso en algún formulario.

```
const TextFieldWithOptions = ({
  textFieldValue = 'text',
  optionFieldValue = 'option',
  value = { [textFieldValue]: '', [optionFieldValue]: '' },
  name,
  options,
  onChange,
  buttonProps,
  menuProps,
  ...rest
}: TextFieldWithOptionsProps) => {
  const [valueState, setValueState] = useState(value);

  const onChangeValueStateHandler = useCallback(({ target }: any) => {
    setValueState((prev: any) => ({
      ...prev,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    }));
  }, []);

  console.log(valueState);

  return (
    <FlexBox gap={4} alignItems={'center'} justifyContent={'center'}>
      <TextField
        id='text-field'
        name={textFieldValue}
        value={valueState[textFieldValue]}
        onChange={onChangeValueStateHandler}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='end'>
              <OptionMenu
                optionFieldValue={optionFieldValue}
                initialOption={valueState[optionFieldValue]}
                options={options}
                onChange={onChangeValueStateHandler}
              />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

```
const OptionMenu = ({
  initialOption,
  optionFieldValue,
  buttonProps,
  menuProps,
  onChange,
  options,
}: OptionMenuProps) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const handleClick = useCallback((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }, []);

  const handleClose = useCallback((option: string) => {
    onChange?.({ target: { name: optionFieldValue, value: option } });

    setAnchorEl(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
        onClick={handleClick}
        {...buttonProps}
        sx={{ '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': { paddingRight: '0px' } }}
      >
        {initialOption}
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id='options-menu'
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={!!anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
        }}
        {...menuProps}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={option}
            id='menu-item'
            onClick={() => {
              handleClose(option);
            }}
          >
            {option}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o es la continuación a tu pregunta?

Comment: es mi respuesta, al menos la que hasta ahora me ha dado resultado, ya que intento capturar en un evento los valores de ambos campos, tanto del textfield como del textfield select

Comment: En ese caso, pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace el código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

he esta usando el componente Autocomplete de MUI, por es probable que en cuentres solución a lo que buscas en el
ejemplo

```
<Autocomplete
                  disablePortal
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
                  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, newValue) => {
                    return option.id === newValue.id;
                  }}
                  value={values.idunidad}
                  defaultValue={values.idunidad}
                  onChange={(event, value) => (values.idunidad = value)}
                  options={dataUnidades}
                  size="small"
                  sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Unidad o Departamento"
                      name="idunidad"
                      required
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      error={!!touched.idunidad && !!errors.idunidad}
                      helperText={touched.idunidad && errors.idunidad}
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me es útil, no quiero un auto completado, lo que buscaba era tener dos campos de entrada para recolectar información de ambos y enviarlos como un objeto con ambos valores en un evento de un formulario